# Select Cast (Scope_identity) and executescalar

Tags: c#, sql

Why doesn't this work? I get an error saying the number cannot be infinity. However, I had to take this away from an insert statement so that it doesn't post entries twice.
Where do I have to incorporate this piece of code to get it to allow my code to loop as a new ID?

```
            cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT CAST(scope_identity() as int)", con);

            int aID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: please show how you are making the INSERT. Scope_identity() should be called within the same transaction/connection, if you call it separately you will not get what you need, aka the last inserted ID within that scope execution.

Comment: why exactly did you have to take it away from the insert? next to the insert is the natural place for `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`...

Comment: If I put it into my Insert statement, it's inside the ID loop where it increments the amount of records being inserted. But this doesn't work. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you can have a stored procedure to do the `INSERT` and return the last inserted identity with an out parameter, as you can see in an example here: http://www.objectreference.net/post/SCOPE_IDENTITY()-return-the-id-from-the-database-on-insert.aspx

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customer_Insert]
    @Name VARCHAR(255),
    @Email VARCHAR(255),
    @Phone VARCHAR(255),
    @CustomerID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Customer ([Name], Email, Phone)
    VALUES (@Name,@Email,@Phone)

    SET @CustomerID = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)
END
```

Comment: I liked your refereced article. see [link](http://www.objectreference.net/post/SCOPE_IDENTITY()-return-the-id-from-the-database-on-insert.aspx)- Explains Scope Identity